# Examining EOL characters in a CSV

Tags: command-line, mysql, csv

I have a csv file that I'm intending to import into a `mysql` table.  I would therefore like to make sure I'm reporting it's `LINES TERMINATED BY` properly.  However I cannot figure out what characters are terminating the lines in this csv.

I'd guess that it's terminated by `\n` (the standard Unix EOL).  How can I determine this for sure?

I've tried

- `cat -v file.csv`
- `file file.csv`

I've also tried using vim and `:set list` which just showed the location of line breaks with `$`

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can create a hex-dump of your file with `xxd` which is part of the `vim-common` package.

```
xxd file.csv | less
```

Then check the line endings:

- 0a => \n
- 0d => \r
- 0d0a => \r\n

Comment: `od -t x1z | less ` -  should be similar, without requiring an extra package.

Comment: Thats very good, for a large file you can even reverse it: `head file.csv | xxd |greo --color 0a` will show it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `file`  to give you an indication of the type of line endings.

Unix:

```
$ file file1.txt
file1.txt: ASCII text
```

DOS:

```
$ file file2.txt
file2.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

and knowing that DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n").

So you can determine what is EOL of any file you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've seen more exotic line terminations in different examples for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21300075/2540204.  Now I'm certain that's not the case here but how would I know if it was?  I feel like I should be able to examine it directly.

Comment: ...Incidentally the result form `file` is `file.csv: ASCII text`

Comment: Then it's Unix so the \n would be EOL

Answer (score 1):

Instead of CHECKING, why not simply SET the line ending style you prefer:

`sudo apt-get dos2unix` will give you access to `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` command line utilities.

These will convert text files according to the names.

*Caveat: files with mixed content **has** been troublesome, I'm not updated on whether that problem is gone.*